# How can I set the product attribute to Use To Create Configurable Product "Yes" programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.8, configurable-product, product-attribute

I've created an  product attribute by using a script. Now in my Model I want to set that attribute's `Use To Create Configurable Product property` to  `"Yes"` based on some conditions. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$attributeId =  Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','your_attr');

if ($attributeId) {
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
    $attribute->setIsConfigurable(1)->save();
}
```